# AC/DC "High" Voltage

Tags: ac, dc, cable-assemblies

I want to carry a voltage along a cable of about 300m, the total resistance is about 2.3 ohms on every conductor, if I have 10 amps of current on the cable the voltage drop will be 23V.My application requires 15 amps so I decided to send through the cable a voltage of about 50V.My question is if it's to send this voltage as AC and rectifies at destination or send this voltage as DC already ?What are the advantages and disavantages ?

Comment: What dc voltage range is your load able to work with? Bear in mind that the volt drop is on every conductor so it will be 46 volts in total at 10A. There will be a lot of power heating the cable up - 460 watts lost in the cable at 10 amps.

Comment: why not wire up 300m of mains voltage and then put a psu to output whatever you need there?

Comment: Well, on the other side I have a SMPS and this 50V is coming from a transformer.@Andyaka I thought that will be 46 volts because in my mind this appears like 1 resistor of 2.3 ohms then the load and finally another resistor of 2.3 ohms that goes to ground.What options do I have ?This resistance I cannot modify.My load requires 12V, every module is working at 12V and is supplied from a SMPS(every module has one).

Comment: The only option you have is to use a higher voltage for covering the distance. The higher the voltage the lower the current you need. And the current causes the power loss. That's why the mains voltage to your house is also transported at several kilovolts before being transformed down locally. It's way more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really doesn't matter whether you send AC or DC over the cable. If you need to reduce voltage drop, you'll have to use higher voltage or thicker cable. For a 300m cable it really makes sense to send the Mains voltage (220V) through it and install a PSU on the other end to produce 12V or whatever voltage you need. If you don't have Mains available, it may even make sense to produce it using an inverter.

PS: having high voltage drop in the cable is not only wasteful, but also dangerous for the load. Unless your load consumes quasi constant current (like an incandescent bulb), you can't realistically guarantee a stable input voltage for it. Even if you use two bulbs in parallel, your power line will likely fry one bulb should the second one burn out.

Comment: My power comes from a generator so it's ok.

Comment: Even if I use a SMPS could fry my circuits ?

Comment: If you use an SMPS (rated for the whole voltage range between the initial voltage provided by the source and the voltage after the drop under full load), and place it near your load, that's OK (except you still waste energy as voltage drop heats up your power line)

Comment: ....Move the generator?

Comment: I cannot move the generator because the application in one remote and small.